# efficient way to remember array index of two large arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have two Fortran arrays in 2 and 3 dimensions, say a(nx,ny) and b(nx,ny,nz). In array a, I need to find out the satisfied points, say values > 0. Then I need to locate the vectors in array b having the same indexes of x and y of those satisfied points in a. What is the easiest and fast way to do it? The two arrays are big, and I don't want to search one element by one element. Hope I explain my problem clearly! thanks!

Comment: do not have reputation to put fortran tag

Comment: [tag:fortran] is an already existing tag. You should not need any special reputation level to use it on your own questions. You also don't need any reputation to edit your own questions, so you should be able to add it.

Comment: Do you need to know all of the indices, or do you just need to do some operation on B at those indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best method, but here's what I would do:

Put a `where` clause inside a `do` loop over the z-values. You can first get a 2D map of valid indices into a logical array if you don't want to recalculate the points every time:

```
program indices
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nx = 3000, ny = 400, nz = 500
    integer, dimension(nx, ny) :: a
    integer, dimension(nx, ny, nz) :: b
    logical, dimension(nx, ny) :: valid_points

    integer :: x, y, z

    do y = 1, ny
        do x = 1, nx
            a(x, y) = x - y
        end do
    end do

    valid_points = (a > 0)

    do z = 1, nz
        where(valid_points)
            b(:, :, z) = z
        else where
            b(:, :, z) = 0
        end where
    end do

end program indices
```

Comment: works ok for small array. Testing real case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not use a temporary logical array, that is superfluous and the compiler can easily handle the `where` statement inline without the additional memory.